# Count between two different dates from same column and table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this information

```
ACCTCCODE | ACCTDESCRIPTION | ISSUEDATE
----------+-----------------+----------------
1031      | Blahdescription | 2018-03-11
1032      | Blahdescription | 2017-04-18
1033      | Blahdescription | 2018-04-15
1034      | Blahdescription | 2018-011-04
```

I want to try and get the dates between two times? For two separate columns. E.g.

```
ACCTCCODE | ACCTDESCRIPTION | FIRSTCOUNT  | SECOUNDCOUNT
----------+-----------------+-------------+--------------
1031      | Blahdescription | 150            23
1032      | Blahdescription | 75             101
1033      | Blahdescription | 3              78
1034      | Blahdescription | 11             23
```

I've tried to create a query with a SELECT within a SELECT but am new to sql so having a bit of trouble making it work.

Here's what I've come up with which works for first count but doesn't work quite right for the second count.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    account AS ACCTCODE, Description AS ACCTDESCRIPTION,
    COUNT(issueDate) AS FIRSTCOUNT,
    (SELECT COUNT(issueDate) 
     FROM Table1 
     WHERE issueDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-2-31') 
                         AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-04-03') 
       AND account <> '') AS SECONDCOUNT
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE 
    issueDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-11-31') 
                  AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-02-01')
    AND account <> '' 
GROUP BY
    account, Description
ORDER BY 
    account, Description ASC
```

Comment: can you describe the logic of 1st and 2nd count

Comment: So I just want to count the number of rows that have the dates between 2017-11-31 and 2018-02-01 for FirstCount. And then the same thing for secondCount, just counting the rows that are between its 2 dates. Both dates come from the column issueDate.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUM() with CASE once for each date interval

```
SELECT account AS ACCTCODE, description AS ACCTDESCRIPTION,
    SUM(CASE WHEN issuedate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '20171131', 112) AND CONVERT(DATE, '20180201', 112) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FIRSTCOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN issuedate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '20180228', 112) AND CONVERT(DATE, '20180403', 112) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SECONDCOUNT
FROM Table1
GROUP BY account, description
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below by using case when

```
select ACCTCCODE,ACCTDESCRIPTION  ,sum(case when issueDate>='2017-11-31' and issueDate<='2018-02-01' then 1 else 0 end)
          as FIRSTCOUNT ,count(*) as SECOUNDCOUNT
FROM Table1
 group by ACCTCCODE,ACCTDESCRIPTION
```